# Why did a chicken cross a road?

Tags: indefinite-articles, jokes

To get to another side.

Can we conclude from the indefinite article "an" in "another" that the chicken did not have a definite plan in mind?

Comment: The famous joke-riddle does feature the definite article: *Why did the chicken cross the road?* *To get to the other side.*

Comment: As Robusto says, this is not the usual wording, but in any case, I don't think we can conclude any such thing.

Comment: There may be a valid query here, but a less bizarre example is needed.

Comment: ***Why did the chicken cross the road?*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_did_the_chicken_cross_the_road%3F

Comment: Are you asking about ***the other*** vs ***another*** as determiners?  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/other-others-the-other-or-another

Comment: I can tell you for a fact, he was trying to commit suicide.

Comment: Well, since the chicken seemingly crossed some unspecified road to begin with, it would seem there was no plan behind it.

Comment: There was a question posted recently about "a man crossed the road" vs. "a man crossed a road" Now, where did I see that?

Comment: Found it: [Why is “a road” incorrect in this test?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/66164/why-is-a-road-incorrect-in-this-test) Why don't you link your question to this post?

Comment: The best response I’ve seen is ***to see a man lay bricks***

Comment: @Mari-LouA - If you want to make a suggestion, it might work better to say something like "How about linking your etc."  I am guessing that you didn't intend to imply that the OP *should have* linked to it in the first place -- but that's the sense that I, at least, get from this wording.  Which seems uncharacteristic of the tactful Mari-Lou I have become acquainted with here.

Comment: @aparente001: I didn't take any offense at Mari-Lou A's not unreasonable suggestion.  But this question was intended a sort of diagnostic, rather like an inkblot.  To have linked to the other question would have interfered with its results  ;-)

Comment: @TimRomano What was the result of the diagnosis? How long have I got?

Comment: @Dan Bron: At the end of a 50-minute session, the man lying on the couch asks the psychiatrist, "So, doc, have long have I got?" The shrink replies "That's it for today."

Comment: Chickens should be allowed to cross the road without having their motives questioned.

Answer (score 6):

First things first: as several commentors have pointed out, the standard form of the joke is¹:

> Why did **the** chicken cross the road?
>
> To get to **the** other side.

That is, the standard joke does use the definite article, which invalidates the premise of the question.

[image: ngram of joke forms, where *get to **another** side* doesn't even appear]

Nevertheless, let us see if we can come up with another example in order to explore the idea that the indefinite article implies lack of certainty.

Let me paraphrase [@NicestHippo on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/nicesthippo/status/585108383985836034), here:

> What should we call this giant advertising board?
>
> PHIL: A philboard
>
> BILL: I have another idea

So from the "a" in *another*, could you conclude that Bill does not have a definite idea in mind?

No? Not convinced? Alright, let's return to the original joke: just how many sides does a road have, anyway?

¹ <sub>See for example, [Wikipedia's article on the joke](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_did_the_chicken_cross_the_road%3F), whose images and references have collected some of its earliest forms and uses, as well as the varieties which have evolved over time: not only is the definite-article version canonical, the indefinite-article version isn't even mentioned or attested.</sub>